# Hosting or deploy R rest Api's

Tags: r, api, server

We have created RestApi's in R. We are able to run the code by using Plumber. But the thing is we need to host or deploy the R code on web (like web api or web services)

```
# myfile.R

#' @get /Sample
Sample <- function(samples=10){
 print(samples)
}
```

Note : Please suggest other than Plumber and Shiny

Comment: Have you tried with `operationalization` from `Microsoft R 9.0.1`  There is `mrsdeploy` package which can do this easily.  check for functions `publishService` `updateService` etc.  The Microsoft R server is not free, but you can have the R client version which is free and can be installed locallly and then connect using `remoteLogin`.  The application side is `swagger` based and you can use a REST client like `insomnia`

Comment: can you please post the required steps to follow for the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is for those who wants to have a comparion of API development with R.

Basically concurrent requests are queued by httpuv in plumber so that it is not performant by itself. The author recommends multiple docker containers but it can be complicated as well as response-demanding.

There are other tech eg Rserve and rApache. Rserve forks prosesses and it is possible to configure rApache to pre-fork so as to handle concurrent requests.

See the following posts for comparison

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/api-development-r-part-i-jaehyeon-kim/
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/api-development-r-part-ii-jaehyeon-kim/